# Foundation-4 Collapsed menu does not appear

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am using the code straight from the Foundation docs, but somehow its not working for me.

This is how I am writing the code:

```
  <nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>MENU</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section" style="left: 0%;">
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
         </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

When I scale down the browser window and I reach the "small" window size, the Menu disappears from the page.
Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need to see the css, as I think the problem lies there.

Comment: CSS has not been modified, its part of the Foundation-4 package. Do you have Foundation 4?

Comment: I don't even know what Foundation 4 is. Do you need to use it? Because it can be done with 3-4 lines of just jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Xarcell, I am not using Foundation just for this reason. I am building a responsive website, that's why I use Foundation. The problem mentioned was just one of the issue I faced with this framework. BTW: Foundation-4 is a responsive web design framework by Zurb.

@Dawood Awan, jQuery and Foundation are linked properly. Rest of the features were all working fine, so I know its linked. The problem I was facing was with the Menu itself.

I am answering this myself because I solved the problem.

The documentation had mentioned that the below mentioned code is optional and hence I was not using it. But it seems that I have to use it (even if its Blank) to make my menu work.

```
<li class="name">
  <h1></h1>
</li>
```

Hope this helps others with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem could be from these lines of code.
But here can be some of the problems:

1. You have not linked jQuery file to the page.
2. You have not linked the zurb foundation files to the page.
3. If you have applied both of these then go here: http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.php    Download a template view their code and compare with your code to check for error.